# Get the closest higher value from a sequence

Tags: python

I have a sequence like: *4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512*

now I have a number

```py
a = 5
```

then

```py
b = 8
```

means `b` is the closest higher digit according to `a` from the sequence.

Now `a = x` then `b = ?`

Comment: This is a slight modification of finding the minimum element from an array, and if the values are just powers of 2 you can find it using just the power formula.

Comment: is there any question like this that you have seen, then please attach a link

Comment: this is not power of 2 it is growing with multiplication of 2

Comment: It isn't necessary that every problem is listed out there, you need to learn how to apply existing concepts to new problems.

Comment: If I understood your question, you probably mean
`b = 2**(np.log2(a) + 1)`

Comment: What if `a` is in the list? Should it return the value equal to `a` or the next one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer two solutions. The first is probably the most obvious and intuitive. The second is more advanced but more efficient.

**Simple and intuitive**

---

Here is a simple intuitive approach. The following function returns the closest number greater than or equal to the argument `num` in the sequence `4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...`. The function first assigns `n` to `4`. Then, so long as `n` is strictly less than the argument `num`, `n` is assigned the next value in the sequence and the comparison is made again. Once `n` is greater than or equal to `num`, we return `n`.

```
def seq_1(num):
     """Returns the closest number greater than or equal to num in the
     sequence 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...
     """
     n = 4
     while (n < num):
          n *= 2

     return n
```

**More efficient, but more advanced**

---

A less intuitive approach but more efficient is obtained by first recognizing that the sequence is defined by

- `a_0 = 4`;
- `a_n = 2 * a_(n-1)` for `n` in `{1, 2, 3, ...}`.

Notice how `a_(n-1) = 2 * a_(n-2)`. Substituting this into `a_n = 2 * a_(n-1)`, we obtain `a_n = (2 ** 2) * a_(n-2)`. More generally, through repeated substitutions, we obtain `a_n = (2 ** n) * a_(0)` or `a_n = (2 ** n) * 4` or

> `a_n = (2 ** (n + 2))` for n in {0, 1, 2, 3, ...}

So the first element `a_0` is `2 ** 2 = 4`, the second element `a_1` is `2 ** 3 = 8`, the third is `2 ** 4 = 16` and so on.

This suggests the solution:

```
def seq_2(num):
     """Returns the closest number greater than or equal to num in the
     sequence 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...
     """
     if num < 4:
          return 4
     return 1 << (num - 1).bit_length()
```

- if `num` is less than `4` we return `4`.
- `1 << (num - 1).bit_length()` evaluates to the closest power of 2 greater than or equal to `num`.

This requires the following knowledge:

- `2` is `10` in binary, `2 ** 2` is `100` in binary, `2 ** 3` is `1000` in binary, ..., `2 ** n` in binary is `1` followed by `n` zeros.
- `bit_length()` is a method defined for Python `int`s that "[r]eturn[s] the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary" ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length)).
- `i << j` shifts `i` left by `j` bits. For example

```
In [1]: bin(1)
Out[1]: '0b1'          # 2 to the power of 0.

In [2]: bin(1 << 5)
Out[2]: '0b100000'     # 2 to the power of 5.
```

**Timings**

---

```
# seq_1(420_000)
657 ns ± 0.55 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
# seq_2(420_000)
116 ns ± 0.416 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing that your sequence is in ascending sorted order then:

```
seq = [4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]

def get_next_highest(seq, a):
    b = None
    for i in range(len(seq)-1, -1, -1):
        if seq[i] <= a:
            break
        b = seq[i]
    return b


print(get_next_highest(seq, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sorted sequence you can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) from Pythons standard library.

```
import bisect

data = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
a = 5
index = bisect.bisect(data, a)
b = data[index]
```

You will have to add a boundary check if you expect `a` to have a value larger than the last element of the list.

---

This code demonstrates how it works with random values.

```
import bisect
import random


def get_next_highest(data, value):
    try:
        return data[bisect.bisect(data, value)]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def main():
    data = sorted([random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)])
    a = 50
    b = get_next_highest(data, a)
    print(data, a, b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```